# Let $C=\dfrac{1}{k}\left [\binom{2k-1}{k}-1 \right ]$ where $k \ge 3$. Show that $C\ge 3$.

Tags: inequality, binomial-coefficients

I have a problem:

> Let $C=\dfrac{1}{k}\left [\binom{2k-1}{k}-1  \right ]$ where $k \ge 3$. Show that $C\ge 3$.

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Have you tried induction on $k$?

Comment: I wrote $$C=\dfrac{1}{k}\left [\binom{2k-1}{k}-1  \right ]=\dfrac{(2k-1)!}{(k!)^2}-\dfrac{1}{k}$$. And I have stuck... :(

Comment: I use $$C=\dfrac{(2k-1)!}{(k!)^2}-\dfrac{1}{k}\ge \dfrac{5!}{(3!)^2}-\dfrac{1}{3}=\dfrac{10}{3}-\dfrac{1}{3}=3$$ with $k \ge 3$. Is it right?

Comment: That looks right, except you have taken that $C$ increases with $k$. You may have to prove that too.

Comment: I don't show that $C$ increases with $k$ as you said :), you mean $f'(k) \ge 0$, where $f(k)=C$.

Comment: @kimtahe6 You can't differentiate a function defined on integers...

Comment: I mean $f(x)=C, \forall x \ge 3$, I don't consider $x \in \Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 2):

Write $\frac{(2k-1)!}{k!} = (2k-1)(2k-2)(2k-3)...(k+1)$ so

$\frac{1}{k}{2k-1\choose k} = \frac{(2k-1)!}{(k!)^2} = \frac{(2k-1)}{1}\frac{(2k-2)}{2}\frac{(2k-3)}{3}\cdot\cdot\cdot \frac{k+1}{k-1}\frac{1}{k} \geq \frac{(2k-1)(2k-2)(2k-3)}{6k} \geq \frac{10}{3}$

for $k\geq 3$ (see the comment below for the last ineqality).

Comment: I think that you have a typo, maybe :) $$\begin{align*}
\dfrac{(2k-1)!}{k!} &=\dfrac{(2k-1)(2k-2)(2k-3)\ldots(k+1)\cdot k!}{k!} \\ 
  &=(2k-1)(2k-2)(2k-3)\ldots(k+1) 
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Nice spotted. Will fix it!

Comment: Thanks **Winther**! No! If you have $\text{LHS}\ \ge \dfrac{25}{6}$ then $C \ge \dfrac{25}{6} -\dfrac{1}{3}=\dfrac{23}{6}$ not $C \ge 3$. I'll finish since your hint. We have $f(k)=\dfrac{(2k-1)(2k-2)(2k-3)}{6k}$ then $$f'(k)=\dfrac{1}{k^2}+\dfrac{4k-7}{3} >0,\ \ \forall k \ge 3$$. Therefore, $f$ is an increasing function. So $$f(k) \ge f(3)=\dfrac{10}{3}$$ Thus, $$C \ge \dfrac{10}{3}-\dfrac{1}{k} \ge \dfrac{10}{3}-\dfrac{1}{3}=3. \ \ \square $$

Comment: Your analysis is correct...but you dont need it since 23/6 > 3 so the bound is already good enough.

Comment: Blaaah... My bad, I have updated it now:) Nice work!

Answer (score 2):

The simplest recursion works. Rewrite the inequality to prove as
$$
{2k-1\choose k}\geqslant3k+1.
$$
If this holds for some $k$, then
$$
{2k+1\choose k+1}=\frac{4k+2}{k+1}{2k-1\choose k}\geqslant\frac{4k+2}{k+1}\frac{3k+1}{3k+4}(3k+4),
$$
hence the property holds for $k+1$ as soon as
$$
\frac{4k+2}{k+1}\frac{3k+1}{3k+4}\geqslant1.
$$
This last condition reads
$$
9k^2+3k\geqslant2,
$$
hence the implication [case $k$ $\implies$ case $k+1$] holds for every $k\geqslant1$. Case $k=3$ holds hence the recursion is complete.

Note how the approach avoids any choice of lower bound of some terms by some simpler ones, until the very end, that is, one eliminates any *clever guessing*. On the other hand, this leads to prove a stronger result than simply $C_n\geqslant3$ for every $n$, hence this relies on a monotonicity property, which might not hold although the final result could.

Comment: Thanks **Did**! I understand your solution. You show that $${2k-1\choose k}\geqslant3k+1$$ then $${2k+1\choose k+1}\geqslant3(k+1)+1$$ But you knew $C \ge 3$. It means $$C=\dfrac{1}{k}\left [\binom{2k-1}{k}-1  \right ] \ge 3$$. It's not natural. :)

Comment: What is "not natural"?

Comment: I'm kidding!^_^ :)